# destination.push is not a function ngResource save() AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ngResource `save()` to a mailer API using `$resource` can be demonstrated here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EakLFygH0QGr5zJ9xqZr

The message sends, however I am getting an error in my console log:

`destination.push is not a function`

- What is causing this error?
- Is the response returned blocked by the error or am I using the `save()` response callback wrong?

Comment: How should look data sended to your server? I've got error `{"status":"error","code":-2,"name":"ValidationError","message":"Validationerror:{\"message\":\"Pleaseenteranarray\"}"}`

Comment: @WooCaSh It will throw an error unless you enter a valid email and a message using the plunker view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$resource` isn't appropriate in your use case. In the Angular [doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource), it says that `$resource` is

> A factory which creates a resource object that lets you interact with RESTful server-side data sources.

In your case, however, what you need is just a POST http call. So, instead of using `$resource`, you do:

```
$http.post('https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json', post).
    success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }).
    error(function() {
        ...
    });
```

I've forked and updated the <kbd>[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kUBku2tLYjfXJ2nsih1f)</kbd>, and it works with no errors.

---

Information from [documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.JSON.html):

> The Mandrill API is a mostly RESTful API. Known caveats:
>
> All API calls should be made with **HTTP POST**.